The three dots menu apears on the last video (Multiple HTML videos)
I am rendering some HTML video tags to play videos. Now the problem is when the user click on the three dots menu, the menu should appear near the button that triggered it but the menu shows near the last video's three dots. I have simplified the code a bit and attached the output as well.
Any help or hint is highly appreciated.
import React from 'react';

const VideoPlayer = ({ src, id }: {src: string; id: number}) => {
  return (
    <div id={`videodiv-${id}`}>
      <video className="w-[230px] h-[250px] object-cover rounded-lg" id={`video-${id}`} controls src={src}></video>
    </div>
  );
};

const Test = () => {
  const videos = [
    { src: '/icons/1.mov', id: 1 },
    { src: '/icons/2.mp4', id: 2 },
    // Add more videos as needed
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {videos.map((video) => (
        <VideoPlayer key={video.id} src={video.src} id={video.id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;


Output
I have given unique ids, also unique keys also added keys to parent containers. Previously I was using a modal to open these in a bigger size. I also tried to test this in another fresh project. Same thing there as well.

That's the default menu rendered by the browser itself, isn't it? Not sure if you even have "access" to that at all, in terms of applying custom formatting. Not sure how one could get it to misbehave like that in the first place either though. Can you provide a proper, testable example of this somewhere online?

I have createad a sandbox. Please have a look.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/flamboyant-glade-yplk4n?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js

Okay, using that I can reproduce the problem in Chrome - but in Vivaldi (which is Chromium-based), it works absolutely fine, the menus show up where they should. Can only assume that this is a current Chrome bug then - and I'm guessing that is something they will have to fix, I don't think there is anything you could do about this from your end.

I believe this is a bug that was introduced in Chrome 125. I tested it in Chrome 124 and it works fine, until you upgrade to 125.

Its resolved on Chrome 126, but reproduces on Chrome 125

are u a Mac user? For us it happens the same but only in Mac, not in windows/linux.

More of a comment rather then an answer
